# OperationalError: No such table - but there is such a table

Tags: python, django, sqlite

While developing my website locally, I didn't have any problems, but when I put it on the server, I got the following error upon trying to access anything that had to do with the database:

```
Operational Error at appname_modelname
no such table: appname_modelname
```

This happens for all my apps and models, including the admin model. I am using SQLite3 for the database. The thing is, when I do `./manage.py shell` the following code runs fine:

```
from appname.models import *
print Model.objects.all()
```

It will list the two dummy objects that I have in the table. In other words, I have successfully migrated everything, and data can be read from the table in that context. Furthermore, I am able to serve webpages and static files without any issues. I tried changing the permissions on the `db.sqlite3` file to `755`, to no avail. I am using Django 1.8.1, running on an Apache server inside a virtual environment.

Comment: try : `./manage.py flush` `./manage.py makemigrations` `./manage.py migrate`

Comment: Didn't work :( It deleted the dummy objects I had set up, but I still get the OperationalError.

Comment: try deleting the db.sqlite3 file

Comment: Nope, re-migrated everything but still get the same error.

Comment: try by removing your migration folder inside app

Comment: Still didn't work. I think it has something to do with the server. As I said, working locally everything is fine, problems only occur when I have it on a server.